# How do you install cgminer on ubuntu

Tags: miner-configuration, cgminer, ubuntu

I have downloaded cgminer for linux and uncompressed it and tried to run it but clicking on the executable file does nothing it is marked as executable and still does not run. Is there something else I should do?

I tried to open this file:

[image: File I tryed to open]

Edit:
Here is a screenshot from the directory cgminer is in from the "ls" command

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. I'm installing Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine to look into the issue.

Comment: I could download, compile and run cgminer with the steps described in my answer without any problem. Did you download the binaries or did you compile it from the source code?

Comment: I downloaded the binarys

Comment: Can you link me the package?

Comment: http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/ I have " cgminer-3.8.5-x86_64-built.tar.bz2"

Comment: It works for me, I ran out of ideas...

Comment: the accepted answer is correct but i would not sudo it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cgminer is a command-line software.

Open a Terminal and change the working directory to where you have your cgminer executable with the `cd` command. For example, if you have it on the Desktop you have to use the following command: `cd ~/Desktop` (where *~* indicates your home directory).

Then, if necessary, mark it as an executable file with the `chmod +x cgminer` command and finally run it with the `./cgminer` command. Note that you will probably need to run it as the root user, so you probably want to run this command instead: `sudo cgminer`.

You can also specify command line options. For example, if your pool URL is *http://foobarpool.net:3333*, your username is *qwertie.1* and your password is *1234* you can run cgminer with the following command so it is preconfigured and will start working right away: `sudo cgminer -o http://foobarpool.net:3333 -u qwertie.1 -p 1234`.

You can also specify lots of options for the GPU, fallback mining pools and other things. For a complete list, use this command: `cgminer --help`.

Comment: This gives me sudo: cgminer: command not found

Comment: Are you in the right directory? Where is your *cgminer* executable placed? Did you use `cd` correctly?

Comment: cgminer is under home/Apps/cgminer. Here is the line from the terminal "/Apps/cgminer$ "

Comment: Try to run the `ls` command in that directory. Does *cgminer* show up in the list?

Comment: yes. I even copied/pasted cgminer from ls to make sure I spelt it right, still go the same result

Comment: Does it work if you run just `cgminer` alone without *sudo*?

Comment: I still get command not found

Comment: Then you are not in the right directory. Can you please provide me with a screenshot of the result of the `ls` command?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory of cgminer.

Type

```
sudo -s
```

Type your password

Type

```
chmod +x cgminer
```

Type

```
./cgminer --help
```